# Can I receive missionaries in my house?

Tags: practical-islam

Missionaries from other religions often comes to the house of everyone in the neighborhood. I used to speak with them, but today I'm trying to avoid them. I should receive them in my house or I must say that I don't have interest in what they have to say?

Answer (score 1):

So one of my friends did something like this. He told missionaries that if you are going to talk about your faith for say 10 minutes, then i will talk about my faith for 10 minutes.

Please do so if you can really well represent your faith the way they do. Otherwise, you can avoid them. If you are living in US/Canda, you can get ICNA (Islamic Council of North America) brochures on Islam and give them some.